# Yii simple rbac - checkAccess is not executed

Tags: php, yii, rbac

I'm new to Yii.
I used this tutorial: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/328/simple-rbac/ to make admin role working.
My accessRules function in controller looks like this:

```
 public function accessRules() {
        return array(
            array('allow', // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions' => array('index', 'view', 'create'),
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions' => array('update'),
                'users' => array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions' => array('delete', 'admin'),
                'users' => array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny', // deny all users
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

If I understood - it should execute checkAccess function from WebUser class when I try to view admin or delete action. My checkAccess function looks like this:

```
public function checkAccess($operation,$params=array(),$allowCaching=true) {
    die("it works!");
    if (empty($this->id)) {
        // Not identified => no rights
        return false;
    }
    $admin = $this->getState("admin");

    return ($operation === 'admin' && $admin == ROLE_ADMIN || $operation !== 'admin');
}
```

So it should view "it works!" but I get

> Error 403
>
> You are not authorized to perform this action.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try changing `'users'=>array('admin')` to `'roles'=>array('admin')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try changing 'users'=>array('admin') to 'roles'=>array('admin')
```